# Not able to extend class in already defined Global class

Tags: apex, class, global-methods

I have a Global class that is part of a managed package of my developer org. In that class, I'm trying to extend another managed package Global class but getting an error as

> Type is not visible: Class_Name

Scenario -
Third-Party Managed Package Class having package namespace "Billing" -
Class properties of Billing package TransportModel and ParameterModel class,

```
Global Class TransportModel {
    Global TransportModel(){}
    Global String name { get; set; }
    Global String value { get; set; }
    Global String unit { get; set; }
}

Global Class ParameterModel {
    Global ParameterModel(){}
    Global String name { get; set; }
    Global String value { get; set; }
    Global String unit { get; set; }
}
```

I've also created a managed package from my dev org which includes the class InvoiceHelper,

```
Global with sharing class InvoiceHelper {
    Global void extendMethod(){
        billing.TransportModel tModel = new billing.TransportModel();
     }
}
```

Now I'm, trying to extend ParameterModel class of the Billing package in my InvoiceHelper class as below,

```
Global with sharing class InvoiceHelper {
    Global void extendMethod(){
        billing.TransportModel tModel = new billing.TransportModel();
        billing.ParameterModel pModel = new billing.ParameterModel();
     }
}
```

Here I'm now getting an error as "> Type is not visible: ParameterModel".

But in the same developer org, I created another class having the same code as above, I was able to extend the Billing.ParameterModel class. I'm getting an error only when I'm trying to extend the billing.ParameterModel class in the InvoiceHelper class.

Has anyone faced the issue of Salesforce throwing an error to extend another managed package Global class in the dev org Global class which is part of the managed package?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to follow. Please include sample code. Clarification: are you trying to change a class in an already-released managed package to make it extend a different class?

Comment: Yes right. I've already released a Global class in a managed package and in that class I'm trying to extend another managed package Global class. Though when I created a global class in my subscriber environment, I'm able to extend it but not another managed package Global class.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include code snippets to make it possible to follow what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology here is very confused and is muddying whatever the real issue is.

> Subscriber org class which is already part of my org-managed package -
> I included InvoiceHelper class in a managed package

You need to be clear about which artifacts you are using.

- A *subscriber org* is an org that has a managed package installed. If your class is created in a subscriber org other than your own packaging org, it isn't also in your managed package.

  - If you're working directly in your packaging org, it would be helpful to clarify that.
  - If you're working in some other org that has `billing` installed, your class is simply an unmanaged Apex class.
- "Subscriber org class" is not a commonly used phase and I don't understand what it means.
- There's no such thing as an org-managed package.

> Now I'm, trying to extend ParameterModel class of the Billing package in my InvoiceHelper class as below

Your code is not *extending* `ParameterModel`. You're *referencing* it, and *instantiating* it, but you're not extending (subclassing) that class.

Note, if your `InvoiceHelper` class is indeed in a managed package, your ability to change this `global` class is heavily limited by manageability rules.

> Though when I created the same Billing package class in my org, I was able to extend it in the InvoiceHelper class.

You cannot create a class in your org that is part of someone else's managed package or namespace. You may have just created another unmanaged class.

---

In a comment, you suggested that you're working in two different environments - one probably your packaging org, and one a subscriber org for the `billing` package. If that's the case, one obvious possibility is that you have different versions of the `billing` package installed in the two environments.

Another possibility is that you're misinterpreting the class structure of the `billing` package, as the code you're presenting here does not look like what you'll see when viewing managed `global` classes in a Salesforce org.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an update on my query. Sorry for the confusion in the question, I've edited my question to add more clarification. I hope it would make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue.

Salesforce doesn't automatically increase the installed managed package class version, so if we try to use the managed package class property which was created after installing that package, you won't be able to access it.

You've to manually change the version of the managed package to the latest one in the Apex Class properties - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_packages.htm.